# Existe um seletor css que seleciona elementos através do seu texto?

Tags: css3, css-seletores, pseudo-classes

Quero adicionar `background` a linha de uma tabela em que uma das colunas o seu valor seja: ***Valor 1***. Tentei com o [pseudo-classe contains](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors) e pelo `innerHTML`, mas todos sem sucesso.

## Código:

```css
table tr td [innerHTML="Valor 1"]{
  background: red;
}

table tr td: contains('Valor 1'){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- Como eu poderia usar um selector CSS pra selecionar a linha pelo
  texto da coluna?
- De uma maneira mais genérica, como poderia selecionar um
  elemento pelo seu conteúdo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelos seletores que vejo na [documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), não dá pra fazer isso. Mas dá pra selecionar via atributos e valores de atributos, então se você colocar o texto em um atributo é possível sim.

Fiz no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7meLeyz/) pra você ver.

```css
div[atributo_texto="teste"]{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="divTeste" atributo_texto="teste">
teste
</div>

<div id="divTeste2" atributo_texto="batata">
batata
</div>
```

O mais perto de seletor de conteúdo que vejo na documentação é o `:empty`, que seleciona elementos vazios

Comment: Eu vi essa resposta um pouco depois, valeu :)

Answer (score 2):

Complemento o [@Artur](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/68469/artur-o-templ%C3%A1rio) somente com CSS não é possível fazer isso, de acordo com a [documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). Uma alternativa é usar `Jquery`, que pode ser feito assim:

```
$("table tr td").filter(function (){
  return $(this).text() == "Valor 1";
}).css("background", "red");
```

Em uma das respostas dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text), diz o seguinte:

Há uma base muito conceitual para explicar por que isso não foi implementado. É uma combinação de basicamente 3 aspectos:

1. O conteúdo textual de um elemento é efetivamente filho desse
   elemento
2. Não é possível segmentar o conteúdo de texto diretamente
3. CSS não permite a ascensão com seletores

Estes 3 juntos significam que pelo tempo que você tem o conteúdo de texto que você não pode subir de volta para o elemento pai, e você não pode estilizar o texto atual. Isto é provavelmente significativo, uma vez que descendente só permite um acompanhamento singular do contexto. Ascendente ou outros seletores envolvendo outros eixos introduzem a necessidade de soluções mais complexas de percurso ou similares que complicariam muito a aplicação de `CSS` ao ***DOM***.